# Odoo Singleton error when putting more then one attachment

Tags: singleton, odoo, attachment

Hello i am trying to send multiple attachment in one email, here is the code that i used:

```
def action_send_card(self):
template_id = self.env.ref('library.agreement_email_template').id
data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].browse(self.agreement_file.id)
        template = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id)
        for pdf in data_id:
            template.attachment_ids = [(3, pdf.id)]
            template.attachment_ids = [(6, 0, [pdf.id])]
        template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
        return True
```

i tried it with one file its work great but when i try two files or more it gives me the same error.

**ValueError: Expected singleton: ir.attachment(260, 257)**

The agreement_file is declared like this:

```
agreement_file = fields.Many2many(
        'ir.attachment',
        'class_ir_attachments_rel',
        'class_id',
        'attachment_id',
        string="Agreement files",
        required=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some of the solutions in here but it still didnt work. I changed something in the code and somehow i found the solution. Here it is

```
    def action_send_card(self):
        template_id = self.env.ref('library.agreement_email_template').id
        data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].browse(self.agreement_file.ids)
        template = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id)
        for existing_pdf in template.attachment_ids:
            template.write({"attachment_ids": [(3, existing_pdf.id)]})
        for pdf in data_id:
            for new_pdf in pdf:
                template.write({"attachment_ids": [(4, new_pdf.id)]})
        template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`agreement_file` is amny2many, for your particular condition there are multiple `ir.attachment` records assigned. Problem is occurring from line 3 `data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].browse(self.agreement_file.id)`, as `agreement_file` is a recordset of multiple records, you have to access `ids` instead of `id`.

```
def action_send_card(self):
    template_id = self.env.ref('library.agreement_email_template').id
    data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].browse(self.agreement_file.ids)
    template = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id)
    for pdf in data_id:
        template.attachment_ids = [(3, pdf.id)]
        template.attachment_ids = [(6, 0, [pdf.id])]
    template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
    return True
```

or simpler

```
def action_send_card(self):
    template = self.env.ref('library.agreement_email_template')
    template.attachment_ids = [(6, 0, self.agreement_file.ids)]
    template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
    return True
```

Comment: Weird, in the longer version it gives me no error, but it still only sends me the first pdf even though i have two attachments in the agreement_file. While in the simpler version i am getting this following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: my bad, it was a nested list. edited the simple code, try now.

Comment: all good friend, i used your code and changed it alittle and i managed to find the answer.